# Cropping Image using Segment anything model

Tags: python, image-segmentation

```
IMAGE_PATH = "Akher-Saa-001-1934_Page_05.jpg"
import cv2
from segment_anything import SamAutomaticMaskGenerator
import torch
from segment_anything import sam_model_registry
import supervision as sv


DEVICE = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
MODEL_TYPE = "vit_h"

sam = sam_model_registry[MODEL_TYPE](checkpoint="/home/f4/Afifi/sam_vit_h_4b8939.pth")
sam.to(device=DEVICE)
mask_generator = SamAutomaticMaskGenerator(sam)

image_bgr = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
result = mask_generator.generate(image_rgb)

print(type(result))
print(type(result[0]))
print(result[0])

mask_annotator = sv.MaskAnnotator(color_lookup = sv.ColorLookup.INDEX)
detections = sv.Detections.from_sam(result)
annotated_image = mask_annotator.annotate(image_bgr, detections)

annotated_image_path = "annotated_image.jpg"
cv2.imwrite(annotated_image_path, annotated_image)
print(f"Annotated image saved at: {annotated_image_path}")

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(result[0] > 0.5, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    # Crop the region from the original image
    cropped_region = image_bgr[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    # Save the cropped region
    crop_output_path = "cropped_region_{i}.jpg"
    cv2.imwrite(crop_output_path, cropped_region)
    print(f"Cropped region {i} saved at: {crop_output_path}")
```

this is the error I am facing so far:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/f4/Afifi/SAM_FILE/tryCropping.py", line 32, in 
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(result[0] > 0.5, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'

I am currently working on a project to extract photos out of JPEG images like this, I can currently a
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxHG3.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNyhn.jpg)

I need to be able to crop the segmented photos out

Comment: Hey, please show us what you tried so far, if I were you, and if there is always a boarder around the images, I would go with cv2.findContours -> cv2.boundingRect -> crop. But you only have one example in your post and I do not know for sure if this would apply to all your images or not. Generally speaking, edit your post to include what you tried and more images, then we can help you further

Comment: Hello, I just edited my post

Comment: There is no code in your question.

Comment: Hello, I just added the whole code and the problem I am facing